# Choosing an transporter with enough battery ANYLOGIC

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model I've created an automobile robots(AMR) which transports orders. The Automobile robots is a transporter fleet, which is agent type AMR. This agent type has a parameter which is a boolean for needCharging (see figure 1), during my simulation at a certain point a robot needs to charge and the needCharging parameters changes to true.

In my model I want when I seize a transporter that he only chooses a transporter in the fleet where `NeedCharging==false`. So I coded it in the transporter choice condition as `!unit.NeedCharging`. (see figure 2 and 3 which showing the fleet and seize), but somehow he does not link the unit to a transporter in the seize block, how can I fix this that he only seizes transporters which does not have the parameter needcharging states as true.

[image: Parameters transporter]
[image: Transporter Fleet]
[image]

Comment: what is the error message you get when hovering over the little red cross next to `!unit.NeedCharging` ?

Comment: @Benjamin, the answer below was solving the problem! A bit off-topic but I saw your Seminar about UI for anylogic, it was a great seminar and very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
!((AMR)unit).NeedCharging
```